# How to convert PDF saved in image column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pdf, pdf-generation, power-automate

I have a table that stores the HEX values of PDF files

```sql
CREATE TABLE testImage(image_value image);
```

How do I retrieve a value from a table and decode it back to PDF? Can I do this in SQL or Microsoft Flow, for example? I've read about this, but there are many old threads suggesting writing a C# application. I would like to retrieve the BASE64 value and then decode it to PDF.

I tried something like this, but when I decode, I get a corrupt PDF file.

```sql
    select 
    CAST('' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("image_value"))','VARCHAR(MAX)') as base64_img1
from (
    select 
        image_value = cast(image_value as varbinary(max))
    from dbo.testImage
    ) T
```

Comment: [image data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) has long since been deprecated, use `varbinary(max)`

Comment: @Stu Yeah I know, but I have a old database where PDF and JPG are stored in image *sadge*

Comment: Fun fact I tried inserting data into varbinary and image and the result is the same - both inserted values are not equal to the data I originally added

Comment: @KJ It stores HEX in the database

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to make some kind of trigger before, but SQL Server does not have a BEFORE value in the trigger

Comment: Yeah it start from `0x255044462D312` but when I get data from DB that has 65535 length but originally has 118131 length. I tried convert hex to bin and then change extension but I got corrupted file

Comment: So now you realize that `varbinary(max)` and `image` aren't the same after all? One of the difficulties with the legacy (deprecated and soon to be removed) `text`, `ntext` and `image` data types is that they require you to work with them using pointers and the [`READTEXT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/readtext-transact-sql), [`UPDATETEXT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/updatetext-transact-sql) and [`WRITETEXT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/writetext-transact-sql) functions. You don't have this guff with the max types.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I still don't get one thing. Why when I put `0x255044462D312...` to varbinary(max) I receive from it the same value but truncated  (in DB 65535 length, originally 118131 length)

Comment: Okay then... Management Studio suc*s it doesn't return whole value just a part.... I did `cast(convert(varchar(max), image_value, 1) as xml)` and received whole value